# Метка для адаптера recyclerview

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [recyclerviewadapter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerviewadapter) и [recyclerview.adapter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerview.adapter).

А ещё непонятно для чего нужна метка [adapter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adapter).

Answer (score 1):

1. Если посмотреть [случаи, когда эта метка используется без [tag:android]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adapter+-android), то всего 4 вопроса. Нужно убрать метку с этих вопросов.
2. По [recyclerview.adapter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerview.adapter) вопросов больше. Её следует сделать основной, как мне кажется.
3. А [adapter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adapter) трогать не надо (синонимизировать ни к чему не надо), т.к. оно ещё для [listview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) используется.